# Android null pointer exception on start of aplication

Tags: android

when my main activitie starts it gives a null pointer exception.
i think its wehen i give the list view a costom adapter.

LogCat log:

```
10-10 10:07:46.312: D/AbsListView(8971): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-10 10:07:46.492: D/AndroidRuntime(8971): Shutting down VM
10-10 10:07:46.492: W/dalvikvm(8971): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fd6ac8)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.csi_week1/com.example.csi_week1.CriminalListActivitie}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:469)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at com.example.csi_week1.CriminalListActivitie.onCreate(CriminalListActivitie.java:22)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
10-10 10:07:46.502: E/AndroidRuntime(8971):     ... 11 more
```

CriminalListActivitie :

```
package com.example.csi_week1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CriminalListActivitie extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitie_activity_criminal_list);

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCriminals);

        listview.setAdapter(new CriminalProvider(this.getApplicationContext()));

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CriminalProvider provider = (CriminalProvider)parent.getAdapter();
                Criminal criminal = provider.GetCriminal(position);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("criminal", criminal);   
                startActivity(i);
            }});

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.criminal_list_activitie, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

CriminalAdapter:

```
    package com.example.csi_week1;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    /**
     * This class can be used to generate random criminals, and retrieve them based on their index.
     * @author Michael
     *
     */
    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    public class CriminalProvider extends ArrayAdapter<Criminal>{

        /**
         * This list contains the generated criminals.
         * Notice the static. This means that all CriminalProvider classes share the same list.
         */
        private static List<Criminal> criminalList;
        /**
         * This context can be used to acquire the resources.
         */
        private Context context;

        /**
         * Constructor of the CriminalProvider.
         * @param context The context (i.e. the activity) that is using this provider.
         */
        public CriminalProvider(Context context)
        {
            super(context, R.layout.activitie_activity_criminal_list, criminalList);
            this.context = context;

            if(criminalList == null)
            {
                criminalList = new ArrayList<Criminal>();
                fillCriminalList();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the list with all stored criminals
         * @return the list with criminals
         */
        public List<Criminal> GetCriminals()
        {
            return criminalList;
        }

        /**
         * Get a specific criminal 
         * @param the index of the criminal in the list
         * @return the criminal
         */
        public Criminal GetCriminal(int index) {
            if(index >= criminalList.size() ) return null;

            return criminalList.get(index);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a criminals.
         */
        private void fillCriminalList()
        {
            //Load criminal and crime information from resource xml files (see res/values folder):
            String[] criminalNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.criminalNames);
            String[] criminalDetails = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.criminalDetails);

            int[] drawableIds = new int[] { R.drawable.mugshot1, R.drawable.mugshot2,
                    R.drawable.mugshot3, R.drawable.mugshot4, R.drawable.mugshot5 };

            String[] crimeNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.crimeNames);
            String[] crimeDetails = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.crimeDetails);

            for(int criminalIndex = 0; criminalIndex < criminalNames.length; criminalIndex++)
            {
                Criminal someCriminal = new Criminal();

                someCriminal.name = criminalNames[criminalIndex];
                someCriminal.description = criminalDetails[criminalIndex];

                int drawableId = drawableIds[criminalIndex];
                someCriminal.mugshot = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);

                Random r = new Random();
                someCriminal.gender = r.nextBoolean() ? "Male":"Female";
                someCriminal.age = 10 + r.nextInt(100);

                someCriminal.lastKnownLocation = new Location("");
                someCriminal.lastKnownLocation.setLatitude(-180.0 + r.nextDouble() * 180.0);
                someCriminal.lastKnownLocation.setLongitude(-180.0 + r.nextDouble() * 180.0);

                someCriminal.crimes = new ArrayList<Crime>();
                int maxNumberOfCrimes = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.crimeNames).length;
                int numCrimes = 1 + r.nextInt(maxNumberOfCrimes);
                for (int c = 0 ; c < numCrimes; c++)
                {
                    Crime crime = createRandomCrime(crimeNames, crimeDetails);
                    someCriminal.crimes.add(crime);
                }

                criminalList.add(someCriminal);
            }

            Collections.shuffle(criminalList);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a random crime. The name and description are picked from the resource files.
         * @return The random crime.
         */
        private Crime createRandomCrime(String [] crimeNames, String[] crimeDetails)
        {
            Crime randomCrime = new Crime();
            Random r = new Random();

            int randomInt = r.nextInt(crimeNames.length);
            randomCrime.name = crimeNames[randomInt];

            randomInt = r.nextInt(crimeDetails.length);
            randomCrime.description = crimeDetails[randomInt];

            randomCrime.bountyInDollars = r.nextInt(100000);

            return randomCrime;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View criminalView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_criminal_list, null);
            ImageView mug = (ImageView)criminalView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            mug.setImageDrawable(criminalList.get(position).mugshot);

            TextView name = (TextView)criminalView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            name.setText(criminalList.get(position).name);

            TextView bountyTotal = (TextView)criminalView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            bountyTotal.setText(criminalList.get(position).getBountyInDollars());

            return criminalView;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CriminalProvider` constructor you're supplying uninitialized `criminalList` (`null`) to the superclass `ArrayAdapter` constructor. You're only initializing the list after passing the null reference to the super constructor.

Move the

```
criminalList = new ArrayList<Criminal>()
```

to the member variable initialization part:

```
private static List<Criminal> criminalList = new ArrayList<Criminal>();
```

`static` is a code smell here but if you insist on using it, you can e.g. check for the list's `size()` to see whether you need to populate it in the adapter constructor.